# Nested orderByChild for Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get a list of race times for females in a Firebase database that I have. I may have structured the database incorrectly but I can't see why what I am doing isn't working.

I am trying to get a list of users that are female then check what the fastest time is that matches any of the female uid's. But I am stuck with joining the tables.

My database and code looks like this:

[image: Database Example]

```
var userref = rootref.child("Users");
var raceref = rootref.child('Races');
userref.orderByChild("Gender").equalTo('Female').on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key);     
    raceref.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(snapshot.key).once("child_added", function(raceshot) {
        console.log(raceshot.key);
    });
});
```

Then the console only shows the `snapshot.key` not the `raceshot.key`:
-864646859
-305907999

If I manually put the numbers from `snapshot.key` in then `raceshot.key` does show in the console. I don't get any errors so I am confused as to why I can't use the `snapshot.key` for the equalTo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key of a snapshot is by definition a string, so your in your `/Users/$id` the `$id` values are strings. But in the `/Races/$raceid/uid` property you store the value as a number.

My sense is that the comparison fails on the type. If that is indeed the cause, you should be able to fix it by converting the key to a number:

```
userref.orderByChild("Gender").equalTo('Female').on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key);     
    raceref.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(parseInt(snapshot.key)).once("child_added", function(raceshot) {
        console.log(raceshot.key);
    });
});
```